# $H_0=250g$ and $H_1\neq 250g$"

Tags: probability, bayesian, sampling, inference

We have a sample of size $100$ with a standard deviation of $5g$

It was decided that if the sample mean is between $245g$ and $255g$ while the sample average is $250g$ if $\mu=250g$ or $\mu\neq250g$

- 1) Define the hypotheses $H_0$ and $H_1$:

"For me, it would be $H0=250g$ and $H_1\neq 250g$"

- 2) Define the decision rule
- 3) Calculate the risk $\beta$ and $\alpha$

***original text***

[image]

Could you help me please because I do not understand anything.
Thank you

Comment: please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: I edited your question for formatting, but I couldn't even understand what you were trying to say in your second sentence so I couldn't improve that. It looks like something is missing. Please edit.

Comment: Please also edit your title

Answer (score 2):

A hint to get you started (you'll need to clarify your question further for subsequent hints):

Hypotheses should be about population quantities.

$H_0$ and $H_1$ are specific *statements* about those quantities, so saying "$H_0=250g$" makes no sense. $H_0$ doesn't equal some value, it's a statement about a population parameter or parameters (in this case, it should be a statement about $\mu$).

Take a look at a few hypotheses (which you should already have examples of) and compare what you have closely with what those examples.